# How to insert data in my table?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, servlets

I created one login.jsp page...in this page submit button bottom add new user link is there. if i click that link its open new user registration form. i am already create table in oracle, if i give data i want to store in database but its indicate null pointer exception.....line 92 from newuser_db.java my database connection coding is there in newuser_db.java. please help me......
error: line 92 is `stmt1 = con.prepareStatement("insert into userdetails values(ka1.nextval,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,23,'as','14-nov-87')");`

design:
[image]
[image]
[image]

full code:

```
package com.sla;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;


import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class newuser_db
 */
public class newuser_db extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    PreparedStatement stmt=null;
    Connection con =null;
    ResultSet rs=null;


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public newuser_db() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.init();
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.Jdbc.Odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


        try
        {
            con =DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:odbc:servletdb","system","balaji");

        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.service(arg0, arg1);
        PrintWriter out=arg1.getWriter();
        String s1=arg0.getParameter("USERID");
        String s2=arg0.getParameter("FIRSTNAME");
        String s3=arg0.getParameter("LASTNAME");
        String s4=arg0.getParameter("EMAILID");
        String s5=arg0.getParameter("ORGNAME");
        String s6=arg0.getParameter("MOBILENO");
        String s7=arg0.getParameter("PHONENO");
        String s8=arg0.getParameter("PASSWORD");

        out.println("inserted");
        out.println(s1);




        out.println("inserted1");
        //String sql="insert into userdetails values(ka.nextval,"+s1+","+s2+","+s3+","+s4+","+s5+","+s6+","+s7+",56,'de',01-jan-98)";
        PreparedStatement stmt1;
        try {
            stmt1 = con.prepareStatement("insert into userdetails values(ka1.nextval,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,23,'as','14-nov-87')");
        stmt1.setString(1,s1);
            stmt1.setString(2,s2);
            stmt1.setString(3,s3);
            stmt1.setString(4,s4);
            stmt1.setString(5,s5);
            stmt1.setString(6,s6);
            stmt1.setString(7,s7);
            stmt1.setString(8,s8);


            //stmt1.executeUpdate();
            out.println("inserted2");
            stmt1.executeUpdate();
            out.println("inserted3");
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        out.println(e1);

        }


    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.destroy();
        try
        {
            if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
            stmt=null;

        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            if(con!=null)
                con.close();
            con=null;

        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

please help me anyone...i am confused.......

Comment: You are complaining about a NullPointerException at line 92 of you code. Might want to show us line 92 of your code. Of course, you could just look to see what variable is **null** at line 92 of use_db class.

Comment: my database connection code is correct? please check.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a NullPointerException at line 92, seems that **con** is null. Did your code call **init**? I notice that it is not called from the constructor.

Comment: please show me that line....am new for jsp&servlet application please.........

Comment: In your **newuser_db** class, you have an **init** method that opens the connection and thereby instantiates **con**. Did you call it? If not **con** is **null**.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like you've followed one of the horrible tutorials at [RoseIndia.net](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbcconnectivity.shtml). I would suggest reading a better site for JDBC tutorials.

There are so many things that could go wrong with your code. I would suggest that get help from someone knowledgeable in your team; an internet forum can only help you so much.

- `PreparedStatement`, `ResultSet` and `Connection` are declared as class members of the servlet. This is poor coding practice, as these members will now be shared across multiple requests, and any request would be capable of changing the state of these members resulting in vague and confusing behavior for other requests.
- `sun.Jdbc.Odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` is being used to connect to an Oracle 10g Express edition instance. This is a poor choice for a JDBC driver, considering that it is a type 1 driver and meant to be used when you do not have actual JDBC drivers for the database. Use the Oracle 10g/11g JDBC drivers instead.
- You are catching exceptions like `ClassNotFoundException` and `SQLException` in `init`, and printing their stack trace without aborting execution. In this case, any exceptions thrown will be ignored by the container because you printed their stacktrace. So the servlet will be initialized, but it is perfectly incapable of processing requests considering the nature of the exceptions.
- You are overriding `service` and not providing method bodies for `doGet` and `doPost`. This is again a poor practice. Do not override `service`, unless you have a good reason to (and I'm pretty sure you don't have one).

Having said all that, the reason you're most likely getting a `NullPointerException` in your `service` method is probably because an exception was thrown in this line of the `init` method:

```
con =DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:odbc:servletdb","system","balaji");
```

Since you are catching any exception thrown by this line, and not doing anything about it, you'll find that the `con` variable will be null in such an event. Later, when the servlet processes a request, and attempts to create a `PreparedStatement` instance, it will fail, as the `Connection` instance is null.

Comment: thanks I am not working....actually am trying so many days, after i post here, nobody help to me...anyway i will try.....

Comment: Well, if you post meaningful questions here, people are willing to answer. With the effort that you've put into framing your question, and into debugging your problem, you are likely to get answers with similar effort.

Comment: 1. response.setContentType("text/html"); 2.String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"; please explain this two lines why they are using.....

Comment: I don't understand why are continuing to read that piece of rubbish, despite being told that it is poorly written. Read the [JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) from Oracle/Sun instead.